# Laravel Error - Controller not found, but it is there

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

## Laravel 8

To be exact:

```
"laravel/framework": "^8.12",
```

I kept getting this error

[image]

As you guys can see I have that file in my project.

[image]

I also tried restarting my local MAMP server and clear the cache

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

I also did

```
⚡️  mybabies  composer dumpauto                                                                                        
Generating optimized autoload files                                                                                   
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump                                                             
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi                                                                                
Discovered Package: facade/ignition                                                                                   
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy                                                                                   
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors                                                                            
Discovered Package: laravel/sail                                                                                      
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker                                                                                    
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon                                                                                     
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision                                                                              
Package manifest generated successfully.                                                                              
Generated optimized autoload files containing 4683 classes
```

Please let me know what else I can do.

---

**route**

> Route::get('/', function(){ return Redirect::to('/baby/signin'); });
> Route::get('/baby/signin','BabyAccountController@signin');

Comment: Can you show the route definition for this?

Comment: Composer dump-autoload is not needed as that namespace is already loaded.

Comment: what is your laravel version? run terminal code php artisan -V on your project directory and dump on your question.

Comment: `use App\Baby` shows that you are using laravel 7. please highlight the version you are using for better helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you have these in your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers'; // here

public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace) // here
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace) // here
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could comment out the `$namespace` in your `RouteServiceProvider` and use closure based route definitions like so:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\BabyAccountController;

Route::get('/baby/signin', [BabyAccountController::class, 'signin']);
```

Comment: Thank-you, let me try that. I wonder it does Taylor decided to do that.

Comment: `->namespace($this->namespace)` already included.

Comment: Have you tried committing that out and using the closure-based syntax?

Answer (score 2):

**I got the same error when I installed Laravel version 8.27.0: The error is as follow:**

*The way to define your routes in laravel 8 is either:*

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BabyAccountController;

Route::get('/baby/signin', [BabyAccountController::class, 'signin']);
```

**OR**

If you want to stick to the old way, then you need to add a namespace property in the ***app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php*** and activate in the routes method.
[image]

and

```
Route::get('/baby/signin','BabyAccountController@signin');
```

Comment: I rather update the provider file, and kept my route as is, so it's clean.

Comment: I upgraded from 7 -> 8.

Comment: @cyber8200 i also rather update the provider file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel 8.0 or above, your Route code should be as below:

Your current code :

```
Route::get('/baby/signin','BabyAccountController@signin');
```

It should be :

```
Route::get('/baby/signin',[BabyAccountController::class, 'signin']);
```

and don't forget to import controller in `web.php`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BabyAccountController;
```

Comment: It’s on a new laravel 8

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes definition as below:

`Route::get('/', function(){ return Redirect::to('/baby/signin'); }); Route::get('/baby/signin','App\Http\Controllers\BabyAccountController@signin');`

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to @[p-k-tharindu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4886202/p-k-tharindu)

Adding this line into

> app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
    protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Solved my problem.

***Note :***
I don't need to add `->namespace($this->namespace)` in `boot()` because it's already there. Just in case others face this issue to.